# Signal to forked children processes in C / Linux

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing

I have a shared variable set to 0 and then fork N processes. These processes then busy wait for the shared variable to become 1. The parent is responsible for setting this variable to 1. What's the best option here to eliminate busy waiting?

I was looking into semaphores (sem_open, etc) but my understanding is that parent will need sem_post N times so that all presses can proceed.

Comment: Can you use [sigwait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html) in the child process and raise the signal from parent process?

Comment: Since the duplicate Q&A is from 2018, it is perfectly possible there is an earlier Q&A that covers the same topic, probably with someone else as the answerer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create a pipe in the parent process. Each child process closes the write end of the pipe, then calls `read` (which blocks). When the parent process is ready, it closes both ends of its pipe. This makes all the children return from `read` and they can now close their read end of the pipe and proceed with their code.

Comment: I think this would be the easiest option. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this, I sometimes use [atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) operation. You can use atomic flags to notify sub-process, but it creates busy-waiting. So you can use it on a very special cases.

Other method is to create an event with something like `pthread_cond_broadcast()` and `pthread_cond_timedwait()`. All sub-process wait on your condition. When you are ready to go, unlock it on parent process.

Comment: Since OP has multiple processes it would be more appropriate to use a condition (see `pthread_cond_broadcast`) than a mutex.

Comment: @nemequ I think something like `pthread_cond_broadcast` is also written by `pthread_pthread_unlock`. But your argument is correct.

Comment: Doesn't that only work with threads, not processes?

Comment: @melpomene I think it works on both cases.

Comment: @melpomene — I think you have to use [`pthread_condattr_setpshared()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_condattr_setpshared.html) to set the process-shared attribute and then pass that to the [`pthread_cond_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_init.html) function.

Comment: You also have to allocate the mutex and condition variable in memory shared between the processes.